# Could the conference presentation be a part of my abstract？

Tags: presentation, abstract

I wrote the abstract according to my thesis but realized that it's too much for a conference presentation. Could I use a part of the abstract to present？

Comment: I mean, emmm, I wrote an abstract according to my whole thesis. However, when I was preparing my presentation, I realized it was too much for a 15 minitues' presentation. I am wondering if I could use part of the data to present, in other words, some information in abstract will be neglected while some will be stressed. Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure I understand your question ... of course you can present your PhD(?) thesis at a conference and you are also allowed to shorten the abstract in order to fit the conference requirements.

But in general I would rather recommend to re-write the abstract completely because shortened texts tend to be sub-optimal and you might also run into the issue of [self-plagiarism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism#Self-plagiarism) if you take (parts of) your abstract with copy&paste.

If by "Could I use a part of the abstract to present" you mean if you could use a part of your ideas/results etc to present then the answer is also yes. There is no rule that you have to present your whole work at once - often it is even better to present one (shorter) clear message at a conference than trying to get the whole thesis into a presentation.

---- EDIT ----

After clarification of the question ("Does it matter if the content of my conference presentation does not (fully) match the abstract that I have submitted?"):

No, it does not matter. Most people will not even realise it. If you like you can say a sentence or two in the beginning that you will focus on a specific sub-part of your abstract (and you are happy to discuss the other aspects during the coffee break etc). But it is up to you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already submitted my abstract and it has been accepted. I don't think I can make any changes to my abstract at the moment. However, I'm wondering whether my presentation will be questioned if I don't present all information in the abstract. It seems that the presentation does not correspond with the abstract.

Comment: In my experience, no one cares if your abstract and presentation do not match entirely.